# White label sass/css with Webpack

Tags: css, sass, webpack, white-labelling

I'm trying generate multiple css files with webpack for a white labeled application.

I want to run the webpack css/sass loaders one time for each 'brand' and output it in to a separate file. I want to do this as I have a separate variable file for each brand and would want the sass to compile one css file for each brand.

I think I can do this with grunt/gulp, but I wanted to avoid including them in this project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been working on this exact problem lately. I found the [i18n example config](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/examples/i18n/webpack.config.js) to be illustrative of how it's possible to do this. Basically the webpack config can be an array. You could do something like this.

```
import webpack from 'webpack';


export default [
  {
    entry: {
      'brand-1': ['path/to/vars-1.scss', 'path/to/my.scss'],
    }
    // ...
  },
  {
    entry: {
      'brand-2': ['path/to/vars-2.scss', 'path/to/my.scss'],
    }
    // ...
  },
];
```

Obviously you could generate the list, but I wrote it out for clarity. Our SCSS variables are dynamic, so I wrote a script that creates the webpack config and then injects the variables using the [sassLoader.data](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader#environment-variables) option.

You may also want to use [webpack-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-merge) in order to separate the configs.

```
const common = {
  module: {
    loaders: {
      // ...
    },
  },
};

export default BRANDS.map((brand) => (
  merge(
    common,
    {
      entry: {
        [brand.name]: [brand.variableFile, 'path/to/my.scss'],
      },
      // If you needed something like this.
      plugins: [
        webpack.DefinePlugin({
          BRAND_NAME: brand.name,
        }),
      ],
    },
  )
));
```

I'm using the ExtractTextPlugin, and I instantiate one for each brand. I'm not sure if that's the correct thing to do.

I also have not figured out how this interacts with the CommonChunksPlugin, but I hope I can work something out.

Comment: You have sample for this?